# NSColor.init?(cgColor: aCGColor) ambiguous reference

Tags: swift, swift3, type-conversion, ambiguous, nscolor

I want to get an NSColor from an existing CGColor with the func
NSColor.init?(cgColor: aCGColor) according to the docs

```
var linienfarbe = CGColor.init(red:0.0,green: 0.0, blue: 1.0,alpha:1.0)
let textfarbe:NSColor = NSColor.init?(cgColor:linienfarbe)
```

I am getting the error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'init(colorLiteralRed:green:blue:alpha:)

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the optional bit after init:

```
var linienfarbe = CGColor.init(red:0.0,green: 0.0, blue: 1.0,alpha:1.0)
let textfarbe:NSColor? = NSColor.init(cgColor:linienfarbe)
```

The above result will be an optional.

or you can do:

```
let textfarbe:NSColor = NSColor.init(cgColor:linienfarbe)!
```

Also, if you're not going to change `linienfarbe` again, make it an immutable `let`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both solutions do the trick. I copied my line with the optional from the docs, but my knowledge in this case  still seems to be poor.